# Display Recent Posts in BuddyPress Profile

Tags: author, get-posts, buddypress

This is the code I use to get recent WordPress posts.

```
<h2>Recent Posts</h2>
<ul>
<?php
    $recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts();
    foreach( $recent_posts as $recent ){
        echo '<li><a href="' . get_permalink($recent["ID"]) . '">' .   $recent["post_title"].'</a> </li> ';
    }
?>
</ul>
```

I display this code in **BuddyPress Profile Page.**

So I need to modify this code to display only recent posts bu particular author. How to do it?

**Ex : When "Adams" profile I need to display Adams recent posts, When "Milas" profile I need to display Milas recent posts.**

Answer (score 1):

This is quite easy, because you can use `author` as a parameter with `get_posts()`. The following snippet retrieves the 5 latest posts by a specific user, whose ID you need to pass.

```
$author_ID = bp_displayed_user_id();
$author_posts = get_posts('author='.$author_ID.'&posts_per_page=5' );

if($author_posts) {
   foreach ($author_posts as $author_post) {
      // do output like
      echo $author_post->post_title.'<br />'
   }
}
```

Comment: Pass the user ID like so: get_posts('author='.bp_displayed_user_id().'&posts_per_page=5' );

Comment: Server error-500 - this error message appear.

Comment: That´s a server error, yes. But does the snippet create that problem? How do you pass an user id?

Comment: Please don't ask new questions for each issue. http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/207763/bp-displayed-user-id-does-not-work-as-i-expected-buddypress

Comment: I updated my code, should be good to use now.